# Read/Write access to 'Documents' folder for all Android versions?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-10.0

I'm currently using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` as a path. I have requested `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I am targeting SDK 30. I have had success reading and writing a file on Android 8 and Android 11, but not Android 10. Adding `android:ignore="ScopedStorage"` and `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to my AndroidManifest.xml didn't work.

Reading through the official docs, it's very confusing. I tried an alternative approach with an  `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` indent, but all I could navigate was the Downloads folder. I couldn't get to the Documents folder.

There are multiple questions on here that are similar, but don't quite get to the nub of the matter for me. Can anyone please share some light on how to do something as basic as simple file access to the Documents folder?

Comment: Requesting legacy external storage in manifest should be enough to access the Documents folder in the classic way under Android 10.

Comment: Of course the user can browse the whole external storage when the gui for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENTS_TREE opens. Learn the user how to browse. Indeed some things are tricky. That gui does not show internal/external storage by default..

Comment: Thanks. I suspect requesting legacy storage might be being ignored when targeting Android 30.

Comment: No. It is not for an Android 10 device.

Comment: You will not have forgotten to add code for requesting  runtime permissions? And can you use the Pictures or DCIM directory?

Comment: Found the problem (see answer below). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think there's a slight confusion. I noticed that it should be Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory and not Environment.getExternalPublicStorageDirectory

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I have corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was that on this particular Android 10 device there was no "Documents" folder. Manually creating one fixed it. So the real gotcha is that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` sometimes doesn't give you a "Documents" directory depending on the device.

However, I'm not convinced this is the correct way to do this with Android 11 (even though it's currently working for me).

Comment: I'm guessing that this shouldn't work on Android 11, targeting SDK 30. But for some reason it does on the emulator. I get this LINT warning: ```WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no longer provides write access when targeting Android 11+, even when using 'requestLegacyExternalStorage'```

Comment: Of course a pitty that you did not use File.exists().... And used mkdir() ... No it does not provide write access on an Android 11 device as write access is implicitly granted already. Just try without and see you can write. And requestLegacyExternalStorage is only for an Android 10 device.

Comment: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required for Android 8 though.

Comment: Yes. Of course. Indeed. And for all other Android versions execpt Android 11. I told you that it was not needed for an Android 11 device. I asked you to test and confirm that.

Comment: Confirmed: ```android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE``` works on Android 11. But since ```android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE``` works for everything I have tested on, is there any benefit in testing for the SDK in my code? The manifest will still need write access anyway.

Comment: `Confirmed: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE works on Android 11.` My god... You should not request that permission for a test on an Android 11 device and see that you stilll can write. That you should test. Remove it from manifest and at runtime to see.

Comment: I will take a look. I'm thinking that I'm going to run into trouble later on though. All I want to do is to copy an sqlite database from my app's private storage to a public folder, and to restore it. It's amazing how this simple idea is so difficult in Android now. Is there a better way?